# tracking page request with servlets and jsps

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If a user goes on get_appointment.jsp but is redirected, by a servlet, to the login.jsp (as he was not logged in). After successful log in, he should return to the get_appointment.jsp, as the initialization was being done from there.

Now what machanism should be used to track that from which page the request originally came, may be got forwarded to different jsps and servlets and then the user should return to the original (initial page) again.

whats the most common and better way , in general rules. is there any one for the current senarios i explained? there are many, session attributes, url rewriting, global and application, servlet context.

what if user manually changes the address bar and goes to some other place. the session attribute then make him land some time later to some incorrect page.

whats a proper way?.................

for sessions.  if iam  in verfiycreds.java . is there a way to get the page addres from which the request was sent to verifycred.java (i.e login.jsp)?

Answer (score 0):

You could save it in the user's session...

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Could also be doPost(), depending on which you need.
    // Request and response are both abailable there as well.
    ...
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("referralURI", request.getRequestURI());
    ...
}
```

You can then retrieve the URI with `request.getSession().getAttribute("referralURI")`.

If you want to avoid sessions, you could also pass the relevant portion of the URI as a get parameter to the login.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're concerned. Yeah, sessions aren't ideal, web apps should be as stateless as possible, but there's really no way around it. If you need to remember something across requests, you need to store it somewhere.

Comment: Regarding manually changing the address, those concerns greatly depend on how you've designed your application. If you have mingled your application servlet code with your login servlet code, yeah, you might have problems. Sounds like an opportunity for refactoring though.

Comment: so whats your final say on what to use?

Comment: i have been forwarded from login.jsp to VerifyCreds.java   and request.getRequestURI()  in VerifyCreds.java prints out   /Alpinema/verification/VerifyCreds   shouldnt it print login.jsp?  how to do that?

Comment: if iam  in verfiycreds.java . is there a way to get the page addres from which the request was sent to verifycred.java (i.e login.jsp)?

Answer (score 0):

In spring-security, the request is saved at the point, where the request gets intercepted, because it is unauthorized - in the [ExceptionTranslationFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java#176). After successful authentication, the success-handler [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java)/[API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) will be called. This handler redirects to the URL of the request, previsouly stored in the HttpSession by the ExceptionTranslationFilter.

To answer your question, this is a proper way. Look at the way they implemented it, look at the patterns, check out the code.

Comment: I just wanted to stick with core concepts, jsp and servlets. spring is a beast and so are many other frameworks. I am sure they would have options, but my question was to understand the strategy, mechanism and alternatives if any.

Comment: no spring shows how it works with core patterns, but of course it is big. core concepts are described above.

Comment: hmm.. could you tell precise code that I need? which maybe inspired by spring but not containing spring code